# Can I get Mocha to not show passed tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha, gulp-mocha

We just started unit testing at work using Mocha and Karma. We have less than 100 tests, and having to sift through all the passed tests to find the failed ones is already cumbersome. I can't imagine what it'll be like when we have thousands of tests. Is there a way to make it so the passed tests don't show up?

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: Sorry, included it in the tags but not the actual post. I just updated the post

We're using Mocha and Karma.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the test reporter, the [dot](https://mochajs.org/images/reporter-dot.png) reporter should be a more compact representation:

https://mochajs.org/#reporters